# Is ActiveMQ really that bad in clustering?

Tags: activemq-classic, cluster-computing, message, broker

I am coming from IBM/Oracle messaging system and in front of decisions about picking message broker for SOA/microservices architecture. Common candidate was ActiveMQ from open-source space. But I am really not sure after reading this document by IBM:
https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?htmlfid=WSW14229USEN

Messages lost or duplicated is really not something I would like to investigate :-)

Question: Can someone confirm this IBM paper is valid from his/her real-world experience with ActiveMQ running in multi-broker network cluster, or even master/slave? Or in general is ActiveMQ known to really duplicate/lost messages on outage?

Comment: I will give ActiveMQ try with load-balanced dual master-slave cluster configuration (4 nodes) and try to reproduce those tests and create my own results.

Comment: How did you get on?

Comment: Not much, I have docker compose setup of ActiveMQ cluster (3 nodes, each running master and slave, but each master is connected to slave on other node -> the most complex setup), but didn't get yet to testing it....

Comment: @ChrisM - Update, just small update to this. I am now busy with microservices design, actually it looks that I will be embedded broker within each service and create network of brokers. Not sure if I use dynamic or static paths for messages to forward. I will be updating on this, but takes time...